# ERROR: Could not build wheels for cysystemd

Tags: python, pip, systemd

I'm facing an error installing the systemd package:

`pip install cysystemd`

```
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [23 lines of output]
      /usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py:265: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'build_requires'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/cysystemd
      copying cysystemd/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/cysystemd
      copying cysystemd/async_reader.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/cysystemd
      copying cysystemd/daemon.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/cysystemd
      copying cysystemd/journal.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/cysystemd
      copying cysystemd/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/cysystemd
      running build_ext
      building 'cysystemd._daemon' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/cysystemd
      gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/python3.12 -c cysystemd/_daemon.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/cysystemd/_daemon.o
      cysystemd/_daemon.c:1202:10: fatal error: systemd/sd-daemon.h: No such file or directory
       1202 | #include <systemd/sd-daemon.h>
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cysystemd
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cysystemd, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+systemd

Comment: @phd I think you inserted the wrong url

Comment: I would have not spend 15 minutes writing this if I could find the solution by googling. 
As you can see I'm installing cysystemd, the marked question is about systemd which are aliases, but google doesn't know this, and neither I knew before. I'm posting content here so next time when I google the same error, I can find the answer. Maybe systemd and cysystemd are aliases, but as they have 2 different pip names and pages, I think they deserve 2 stackowerflow pages too, so we can find it later by that name too.

Comment: Also why would you downvote an answer when you have a problem with the question? I hate this toxic community

Answer (score -1):

#### You need to install the `libsystemd-dev` package:

`sudo apt install libsystemd-dev`

---

#### `systemd` vs `cysystemd` vs `systemd-python`

The `systemd` is an alias for `cysystemd`. As the pip page suggests, you should use `cysystemd` instead of `systemd` to avoid confusion.

`systemd-python` is the most popular package but it is imported the same way as the less popular packages above: `import systemd`. It's confusing.

That's why if you have no `requirements.txt` telling you which package to install, it is likely that `systemd-python` was is what you're looking for.